# What hosted analytics offers IP recording?

Tags: php, analytics

I'm looking for a free hosted analytic service that logs IP addresses. My first choice would have been Google Analytics, but apparently they do not offer IP logging.

Hosted software only, please. Thank you!

Comment: What specific functionality are you looking for that requires IP logging?

Comment: For such specific information, you are better off checking your server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicky logs IP addresses, is externally hosted, and is generally pretty awesome. They have a free tier that might fit your needs (no more than 3000 daily pageviews). http://getclicky.com/

Answer (score 0):

Another awesome analytics service that offers IP logging would be either a self-hosted piwik install or [reinvigorate.net](http://www.reinvigorate.net).<del>, which even offers a free plan</del>.

EDIT: Reinvigorate does not offer free plans anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Piwik](http://piwik.org/). It's quite similar to Google Analytics, and has an option to capture IP address.